# The abbreviation of "debit" is "dr."

Tags: abbreviations

How come "dr." means "[debit](https://www.accountingtools.com/articles/what-is-the-abbreviation-for-debit-and-credit#:%7E:text=The%20abbreviation%20for%20debit%20is,while%20a%20credit%20(cr.))"? Where does "r" come from? Thank you!

Comment: If you Google "why is debit abbreviated dr", there are many pages answering this.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! I did a different search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://www.jstor.org/stable/40697913

Originally debits were associated with an individual who had a debt, that is a  "**d**ebto**r**".

[source](https://www.basicaccountingconcepts.education/why-is-the-bookkeeping-abbreviation-for-debit-dr/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: Interesting - when I did accounting at college, half a lifetime ago, I was told it was for 'draft'.